# Android MediaPlayer change live stream's URL

Tags: android, media-player

I have a problem with changing URL of live stream in the MediaPlayer instance. When I tap on a ListView item for a first time, live streaming is started and video is displayed, but if I click on another object in the ListView, stream is not changed, the same stream continues to play which was executed at first time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl {

    SurfaceView videoSurface;
    MediaPlayer player;
    VideoControllerView controller;

    ArrayList<Channel> channels;
    Channel clickedChannel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
        SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
        videoHolder.addCallback(this);
        controller = new VideoControllerView(this);
        player = new MediaPlayer();

        channels = new ArrayList<Channel>();
        CreateChannels();

        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, channels);

        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                        + id);
                clickedChannel = channels.get(position);

                        }
                    }
                }

                PlayStream(clickedChannel.Streams[0].URL);

            }
        });

    }

    public void PlayStream(String URL) {

        try {
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(URL));
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
            player.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// missed code

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        controller.show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        player.setDisplay(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
        player.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem by recreating player instance every time

```
public void PlayStream(String URL) {
        releaseMP();
        try {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDisplay(videoHolder);
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(URL));
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
            player.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void releaseMP() {
        if (player != null) {
            try {
                player.release();
                player = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMP();
    }
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
```